# Plus versus Union in probability theory

Tags: probability-theory

I'm studying the theoretical aspects of probability. I'm getting confused about the usage of union ($\cup$) and a plus ($+$) between events.

In one of the beginning lessons we defined an event as a subset of the sample space ($\Omega$). Then, when defining operations that can be applied to those events, it says:

$$A\cdot B = \{\omega \in \Omega|\omega \in A \text{ and } \omega \in B\}$$
And from what I've seen the set theory symbol $\cap$ is never used. The intersection of two events is always written as multiplication ($\cdot$).

However, when it comes to the union it gets confusing. It says here:

$$A \cup B = \{\omega \in \Omega| \omega \in A \text{ or } \omega \in B\}$$
Okay that's clear enough, just like the standard set theory union. But then there's this sentence below:

If $AB = \emptyset$ then $A\cup B = A + B$. What confuses me here is the fact that we have not yet (or anywhere for that matter) defined what addition ($+$) even means in the context of events.

So I ignored this for a while but now as I move on this affects my understanding of other formulas. For example, when defining probability we said that one of the axioms was:
$$\forall(A_1, A_2, ...) \text{ where } A_iA_j = \emptyset (i \neq j) \quad P\bigg(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\bigg) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P(A_n)$$
On the right hand side we're just adding probabilities, which are numbers, so no problems there. On the left hand side however we have the probability of the sum of events (which, I repeat, is defined nowhere). Now the reason I'm confused here is because it seems to me that this is written like this on purpose. We were given that $i\neq j \quad A_iA_j = \emptyset$ so by their own definition this would mean that $A_i + A_j = A_i \cup A_j$. So why couldn't have the whole statement been written as (with the same conditions from above):

$$P\bigg(\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n\bigg) = \sum_{n-1}^{\infty}P(A_n)$$

To summarize the entire questions: What does addition mean in context of events in probability, and is it truly different from the union of events?

Thanks.

Comment: Apparantly if $A+B$ is used then $A+B=A\cup B$ **and** extra information is provided: $A$ and $B$ are *mutually exclusive events*, i.e. it is not possible that both events occur. Also it is common to speak of *disjoint* events. In that special case $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)$ because measures are additive. It is not a necessity that you practicize this notation yourself (I never do, and have seen it not very often) but of course you must know what is meant by it.

Comment: @drhab So it carries no special meaning in the context of the operation itself, just like a 'note' to indicate that they're exclusive?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. Don't worry about it and if you encounter it then just know that $A\cap B=\varnothing$ (or $A\cdot B=\varnothing$ it you like).